# What does it mean if my Asp.Net session has IsNewSession == true, and should I care?

Tags: asp.net, session

To start with, this is code that I inherited and the person who wrote it is no longer here nor available to question.

I have users in production getting annoyed at randomly being logged out of our Asp.Net MVC application (According to references our MVC libraries are version 5).  After flailing about in the code and website for a while I think I have isolated what users are seeing to the following bit of code:

```
public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // check if session is supported
        if (ctx.Session != null)
        {

            // check if a new session id was generated
            if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
            {

                // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must
                // have timed out
                string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                if ((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                {
                    SessionVariables.Current.User = null;
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/Logon");

                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I'm not totally sure why this code is needed (why would you attribute this instead of making it global) but I have seen variations of this code around the internet in my searches but not with description of why you'd want it.

Regardless, it is already in our code base and the issues that we are having seems to be that if the user is idle in a window for a small period of time and then they do something, `ctx.Session` is not null but `ctx.Session.IsNewSession` is true.

This implies to me that for some reason Asp.net decided this user needed a brand new session started up for them, and since we have no idea who this user is (since all their session data is gone since ... it's a new session) we need to log them out and make them log in again.

This all seems logical except I just finally was able to hit a breakpoint inside the `IsNewSession` if statement.  What's odd to me is that my Session actually looks 100% filled out (and filled out correctly).  This means it correctly knows who I am, and all other information that only gets put into the session when you successfully log in.

Furthermore, `ctx.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true, and it has the correct login name.

Everything seems to point that I have a valid session, but since this code is making the design decision that if Asp.Net creates a new session I must be logged out, the user is getting logged out.

So my question is:

1. What does `Session.IsNewSession` mean in practical terms?
2. Is it correct to always log the user out when `IsNewSession` is true?
3. Are there any ramifications for not logging the user out as long as they are listed as authenticated and has valid session data?
4. What causes Asp.Net to create a new session and yet still re-use previous session data?
5. My understanding with session expiration was it was caused by the provider layer, in that Asp.Net wouldn't even have any session data if the session has expired.  Is that not the case?

As a quick side note, we are currently using Redis as our session store.    Also, if relevant the application is being hosted on Azure websites (and I'm not sure how that affects session expiration).

Comment: In simplest terms, it's saying that a new session was started when an *existing* session was present, but had timed out. When the cookie containing the prior session was sent back to the web server, that session had expired, so a new session was built (hence IsNewSession==true) because that session id differs from that of the new one constructed.

Comment: I guess I should have added that FormsAuthentication.Timeout shows an 8 hour timeout, yet htis happened about 5-10 minutes after initially logging in.  So theoretically the session shouldn't have timed out in that time period right?

Comment: FormsAuthentication timeout is not the same as session timeout.

Comment: Have you inspected the possibility that some sort of error or content change on the site is occuring, either of which can destroy a current session?

Comment: I have not, but that gets back to my original question is should I even care about a new session if the previous session timed out due to either an error or a content change?  Presumably users should remain logged in when those happen, especially with an out of process session state store such as redis?  It also seems like any load balancing would completely nuke user sessions if not 100% sticky with this code

Comment: I would be concerned if sessions are being torn down in an unexpected manner. Is there a possibility something in your session management layer is behaving improperly?

Comment: Well after much head slamming it appears that the RedisSessionProvider sets an expiration of 20 minutes by default on the session data in Redis, but *NEVER* resets the expiration unless you change data in the session.  So that seems to be the root cause of sessions going away (though I don't know how I saw session data when a new session ocurred)

Answer (score 10):

ASP.NET creates a new Session any time a browser without a current session navigates to the site. So even if someone isn't logged in, they'll still have a Session. Likewise, if one session expires, a new session will be created the next time the browser makes a request. This new session won't have "session data" stored in it, but `ctx.Session` will not be null. Also, if you have multiple servers and the load balancer happens to route the user to a different server, then that new server will try to start a new session.

Session state is tracked separately from Authentication state, meaning that one can expire while the other is still valid. For well-written applications, this typically won't cause any problems. However, some applications pre-load information into the session upon login, and treat the session as a kind of cache for this information for the length of the session. Or, they will set values on the session when the user performs certain actions, and later actions  will expect those values to be on the session, because the user should have navigated through those earlier actions to get there. (e.g. a Wizard interface, where each step saves values to the session, to be used when the user clicks "Finish" on the final step.)

It's possible that your application at some point was expecting data to be on the session which wasn't there, and the developers realized it wasn't there because ASP.NET had automatically renewed the session, losing all the previously-set session data. Rather than redesigning their use of session data, they chose to make it so that any time they lose the session they'll also force the user to go back to a sane starting position, where pages won't break in weird ways just because session-stored data was lost.

Comment: very well written comprehensive answer!!